# Custom recovery, can it brick my phone?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rooting, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, twrp

I want to root my phone Samsung Galaxy J1 2016 (SM-J120zn). I tried using kingroot, root genius, SRSRoot, but it didn't work so I decided to try to do rooting manually.

I tried looking for my model of custom recovery from Clockwork, Cyanogen and TWRP, but i can't find anything for my device. The closest is Samsung Galaxy J1 ace (SM-J110H).

If i use the custom recovery from the model SM-J110H, will it brick my phone? Can changing custom recovery brick my phone?

Thanks :)

Comment: Rooting and custom recovery are two different things (device can be rooted but have stock recovery).  Next, if your device doesn't have a custom recovery, flashing a recovery meant for another device is inviting trouble. You may be able to recover if you are lucky - you can't be sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first i will answer your question. If you want to use a recovery made for a complete Another model for your phone, yes it will brick your phone. Even though another model is very similar to your phone's model, it's not identical! There will always be some differences internally. For such cases you have to **port** the recovery. Before going for porting, Go to xda forums I'm sure there you will find a recovery for your model. But if you don't find it there, you need to port one from different model to your own.

For recovery porting is not easy and very risky I'll advise you to take help of someone who is well experienced in this. And proceed on your own risk.
Another part i would like to add is flashing recovery and rooting a phone are completely different concepts. Please read thoroughly on xda forums before proceeding.